# Save for Web changes color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

every time I save for web in Illustrator, my colors change. I've looked this up, but every solution I find, the option is grayed out for me. In `Edit > Color Settings` everything is grayed out. Also `edit > Assign Profile` is also grayed out. I've changed the document over to RGB from CMYK and it still converts my colors when using "Save for Web". I need to use "Save for Web" because of the easy scalability it has because I need to scale something up in different various sizes. I also noticed in the settings of "Save for Web" that Convert to sRGB is checked and is grayed out so I can't uncheck it.

Comment: How did you setup your document?

Comment: I can't exactly recall the exact settings, but the color mode was set to CMYK and Profile was set to Custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the options on the "Save for Web" dialog?

How many colors are using in your GIF?
Is the option for "sRGB" ticked?

I would set **256** in your Colors and untick the **Convert to sRGB** option.

[image]

Comment: What if I was wanting to save a PNG?

Comment: Same process. Choose "Save for web" but in the drop down select PNG instead of GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the doc to RGB is correct, but you also may have to convert individual colours in your palette to RGB. They may be CMYK or even Pantone colours. You may have to change the colour of every object on your artboard. Here's a tip to expedite the process a little: select a 'good' RGB swatch in your palette, and then command-click the 'bad' one it's replacing, so that both are selected. Now in the swatches menu select 'merge swatches' and the 'bad' colour will be replaced by the 'good' colour on every object that has the 'bad' colour applied to it. Both colours have to be global, or both not, for the merge to not be greyed out.